# Find anagrams of a given sentence from a list of words

Tags: python-3.x, anagram

I have a sentence with no spaces and only lowercase letters, for example:

```
"johndrinksmilk"
```

and a list of words, which contains only words that could be anagrams of the sentence above, also these words are in alphabetical order, for example:

```
["drink","drinks","john","milk","milks"]
```

I want to create a function **(without using libraries)** which returns a tuple of three words that together can form the anagram of the given sentence. This tuple has to be the last possible anagram of the sentence. If the words in the given list can't be used to form the given sentence, the function should return None. Since I know I'm very bad at explaining things I'll try to give you some examples:

For example, with:

```
sentence = "johndrinksmilk"
g_list = ["drink","drinks","john","milk","milks"]
```

the result should be:

```
r_result = ("milks","john","drink")
```

while these results should be wrong:

```
w_result = ("drinks","john","milk")
w_result = None
w_result = ("drink","john","milks")
```

I tried this:

```
def find_anagram(sentence, g_list):     
g_list.reverse()
for fword in g_list:       
    if g_list.index(fword) == len(g_list)-1:
        break
    for i in range(len(fword)):
        sentence_1 = sentence.replace(fword[i],"",1)
    if sentence_1 == "":
        break
    count2 = g_list.index(fword)+1
    for sword in g_list[count2:]:
        if g_list.index(sword) == len(g_list)-1:
            break
        for i in range(len(sword)):
            if sword.count(sword[i]) > sentence_1.count(sword[i]):
                break
            else:
                sentence_2 = sentence_1.replace(sword[i],"",1)
        count3 = g_list.index(sword)+1
        if sentence_2 == "":
            break
        for tword in g_list[count3:]:
            for i in range(len(tword)):
                if tword.count(tword[i]) != sentence_2.count(tword[i]):
                    break
                else:
                    return (fword,sword,tword)
return None
```

but instead of returning:

```
("milks","john","drink")
```

it returns:

```
None
```

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong? If you think my function is bad feel free to show me a different approach (but still without using libraries), because I have the feeling my function is both complex and very slow (and wrong of course...).

Thanks for your time.

Edit: new examples as requested.

```
sentence = "markeatsbread"
a_list = ["bread","daerb","eats","kram","mark","stae"] #these are all the possibles anagrams
```

the correct result is:

```
result = ["stae","mark","daerb"]
```

wrong results should be:

```
result = ["mark","eats","bread"]   #this could be a possible anagram, but I need the last possible one
result = None        #can't return None because there's at least one anagram
```

Comment: Can you explain why your test cases pass and fail? I'm unsure of exactly what you want.

Comment: Sure. The test "if g_list.index(fword) == len(g_list)-1:" looks if fword is the last word in the list, because if it is the last I can't search for 2nd and 3rd word. So I can't find any tuple of three words which are the anagrams of the given sentence. Same with "if g_list.index(sword) == len(g_list)-1:", if the second word found is the last of the list, there won't be any third word to be found so I should search for another first word (fword). "if sword.count(sword[i]) > sentence_1.count(sword[i]):" makes sure the second word contains characters which can be found in the given sentence.

Comment: I still don't really get it. Can you give me more examples of what a correct result is?

Comment: Tests like "if sentence_1 == :"" " and "if sentence_2 == "" ": make sure I didn't find two words that together complete the anagram (because I need three words, not two". The last one:  "if tword.count(tword[i]) != sentence_2.count(tword[i]):" makes sure all the letters of the third words are contained in the sentence, otherwise that's not the right word.  Thank you for your help and if I still didn't explain myself feel free to let me know. I'll try to give you more examples.

Comment: Sorry, I meant examples like what other tests would be considered correct for `"johndrinksmilk"`. You provide one example of `r_result`, is there more examples that would qualify for the same string? If so, please provide them so I can understand it better. :)

Comment: I edited the question with more examples. The correct result is always only one: the last possible anagram in alphabetical order.

Comment: Okay I understand your query now. Thanks for the extra examples. Give me a bit, I'll see what I can do haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if it works with all of your cases:

```
def findAnagram(sentence, word_list):
    word_list.reverse()
    for f_word in word_list:
        if word_list[-1] == f_word:
            break
        index1 = word_list.index(f_word) + 1
        for s_word in word_list[index1:]:
            if word_list[-1] == s_word: break
            index2 = word_list.index(s_word) + 1
            for t_word in word_list[index2:]:
                if (sorted(list(f_word + s_word + t_word)) == sorted(list(sentence))):
                    return (f_word, s_word, t_word)
```

Hopefully this helps you